# Are there any guidelines for text capitalization in mobile applications?

Tags: android, ios, design-patterns

Are there any *Guidelines for Text Capitalization in Mobile Apps*? I am wondering if there are any patterns that should be followed for user-facing text (such as `Button`s or `TextView`s) - such as **Only capitalize the first word**, or **Capitalize Like a Book Title**. Do such guidelines exist - or is this simply a **Do WhAt *YoU tHiNk* LoOkS bEsT** concept?

Comment: Capitalising what?  Do you mean source code?

Comment: @Simon - I mean user-facing text - like text on `Button`s or `EditText`s

Comment: Okey dokey. Should have realised that with 8k rep, you weren't asking about coding conventions ;)  Good question.  I've never seen any guidelines but my personal preference, and the one which is easiest on the eye to me, is sentence case.

Answer (score 1):

Android:

You will see by convention that tab and list section header labels are all upper-case on the Android platform.  Design guidelines do recommend Sentence capitalization, refer to http://developer.android.com/design/style/writing.html for more information.

iOS:

The HIG (Human Interface Guidelines) is the definitive design reference (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/design/index.html).  There is nothing specified re: text capitalization in this doc.

So other than the Android conventions mentioned above, DWYTLB ;-)